# How to specify context with Flux in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I am following
[Kustomize helm example](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2-kustomize-helm-example)

With original tutorial command

```
flux bootstrap github --context=staging --owner=${GITHUB_USER} --repository=${GITHUB_REPO} --branch=main --personal --path=clusters/staging
```

I got

```
✗ context "staging" does not exist
```

This is what watch helmrelease shows
[image]

Output sources all
flux get sources all

```
NAME                        REVISION        SUSPENDED   READY   MESSAGE                                                                        
gitrepository/flux-system   main/3fabbc2    False       True    stored artifact for revision 'main/3fabbc21c473f479389790de8d1daa20d207ebd6'    
gitrepository/podinfo       master/132f4e7  False       True    stored artifact for revision 'master/132f4e719209eb10b9485302f8593fc0e680f4fc'
```

How to create context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `context=${K8S_CLUSTER_CONTEXT}` for example, I am using [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/) so I have `--context=kind-kind` or you run

```bash
export K8S_CLUSTER_CONTEXT=kind-kind

flux bootstrap github \
 --context=${K8S_CLUSTER_CONTEXT}
 --owner=${GITHUB_USER} \
 --repository=${GITHUB_REPO} \
 --branch=main \
 --personal \
 --path=clusters/staging
```